# Would my files still be safe if something went wrong with my computer?

Tags: ubuntu-one

Just curious about Ubuntu One- for example, if one day, my computer wouldn't be able to boot, would everything be backed up safely? Or if my hard drive became fried or whatever- would it still be safe, or would it realize the files were gone and delete them from the cloud?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your files would be safe in both of those circumstances.

But as you rightly allude to, Ubuntu One isn't a backup tool. If you accidentally delete a file, that file will also be deleted on the cloud.

Comment: I think it's important to note that while the files might be safe in both of those circumstances, there's many other scenarios in which they woulnd't be safe. For example, if a user accidentally deletes a portion of the spreadsheet and saves the file, that change would eventually propagate to Ubuntu One. For important files, you'll want to use version control or incremental backups.

Comment: I would have added an "under normal circumstances". Would be rather cruel if the Ubuntu One server fell over at the same time.  Remenber: Ubuntu one is NOT a backup tool. It is a synch tool so you can access files anywhere you have a connection to the web. If files are important MAKE A REGULAR BACKUP.